# Como fazer um ponteiro polimórfico com o ponteiro this no parâmetro?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, ponteiro, classes-abstratas

Por exemplo, em Qt (me corrijam, se a lógica estiver errada, não mexo com Qt faz tempo), você pode fazer isso:

```
QLabel label = new QLabel(this);
```

Agora vamos supor:

```
#include <iostream>
class AbstractBase
{
    public:
        virtual void A() = 0;
};

class DerivedClass : public AbstractBase
{
public:
    void A()
    {
        std::cout << "ClassA";
    }
    DerivedClass(AbstractBase* Base)
    {
        A();
    }
};
int main()
{
    AbstractBase* A = new DerivedClass(this);
}
```

Mas o compilador devolve: "invalid use of this in non-member function".
Qual a maneira correta de adicionar o parâmetro 'this' nesse caso? (`AbstactClass*`, por que ele é derivado.) Isso é possível (referenciar o A como o parâmetro)?

Comment: O erro indicado é porque você está usando `this` fora do contexto de uma classe. Você vai precisar de uma variável do tipo `AbstractBase*` ali. Fora isso, você está chamando um método virtual em um construtor, o que não funciona em C++.

Comment: Isso é apenas um teste seu ou parte de um programa maior? O que de fato você quer fazer?

Comment: @C.E.Gesser O exemplo é representativo;

Comment: Ok, mas acho que é preciso mais insumos. Você não usa o parâmetro `Base`, por exemplo, então é complicado sugerir alguma coisa sem saber pra que ela vai ser utilizada.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser Veja as edições.

Comment: Cometi um equívoco ao perguntar; vou deletar a pergunta.

Comment: Hum... continuo não vendo a sua necessidade de passar o parâmetro nesse caso. Você está querendo fazer algo como o Qt, onde se passa um objeto que vai ser o dono do objeto recém constuido?

Comment: @C.E.Gesser O Qt é apenas um exemplo.

Comment: É que você não pode usar `this` onde você está usando, porque `this` significa "um ponteiro para a o objeto sob o qual o método atual está sendo invocado", e você está na função `main`, que é uma função livre, não é membro de nenhum objeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O exemplo do [`QLabel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html) com o parâmetro `this` faz sentido se o código estiver sendo executado no contexto de uma classe que pode conter um `QLabel`, uma instância de `QWidget`, já que o primeiro parâmetro seria o elemento "pai" (*parent*) do label.

Entretanto, fora de uma classe que implemente `QWidget`, o código não vai funcionar.

No seu caso, creio que você precisa apenas criar a classe, sem o `this` como argumento:

```
 AbstractBase* A = new DerivedClass;
```

Comment: Esclareci o final da pergunta.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Editei a resposta. Não acho que existe uma instanciação com `this` a não ser que você queira passar a referência da classe onde o código está executando para o construtor do objeto sendo instanciado.

Comment: Obrigado :). Era isso mesmo. Queria , tambem, mostrar o parente do objeto.

Answer (score 2):

A expressão `this` resulta em um ponteiro para o objeto em que você está chamando a função membro no momento. Não faz sentido escrever `this` fora de uma função membro já que não existe objeto nesse caso e o compilador vai reclamar.

Se você quer um ponteiro para o objeto atual dentro do construtor, simplesmente escreva `this`. Você não precisa ler ele como um parametro. O tipo do `this` será o da classe na qual você escrever a expressão, mas você pode converter para uma classe base sem problemas.

```
DerivedClass()
{
    DerivedClass* self = this;
    AbstractBase* base = (AbstractBase*)this;
}
```

No caso do exemplo do Qt que você escreveu, essa linha deve aparecer dentro de uma classe. O objetivo é passar para a `QLabel` quem é seu parente.

Um outro problema:

```
AbstractBase* obj = new DerivedClass(obj);
```

Isso é válido. Mas note que o construtor vai ser executado **antes** que a variável `obj` receba o objeto. Então o valor passado como argumento aqui é lixo. O clang dá o seguinte alerta:

> **warning:** variable 'obj' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi bem qual é o objetivo do código, porém você está utilizando a palavra chave *this* fora do contexto do método de uma classe, é isso que está errado.

**this** um ponteiro para a classe do contexto atual, como você está dentro de uma função e não um método, não existe contexto de classe válido para você neste momento, daí o erro gerado pelo compilador.

Comment: Esclareci a pergunta.

Comment: Lucas. Não existe nenhuma possibilidade de você usar a palavra chave this dentro de uma função! Esta é uma diferença entre C++ e Java, C++ possui elementos de programação estruturada como funções enquanto Java só possui métodos.